# Difference between 2 class definitions regarding contravariant type?

Tags: scala, types, field, contravariant

```
class Contravariant[-T](val other:T)
```

> error: contravariant type T occurs in covariant position in type T of value other

However this one succeeds

```
class MMX[-T](x:T)
```

What is the difference?

Thanks

Comment: Because if prefix the argument with a `val` then it becomes a public field and as such a getter is created using **T** as its return type, which is not possible because **T** is _contravariant_.

Answer (score 2):

As Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64215066/difference-between-2-class-definitions-regarding-contra-variant-type#comment113552665_64215066), in the first example, `other` is a field, and fields cannot be contravariant (as [Dmytro Mitin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5249621/dmytro-mitin) pointed out, not fields with modifier `private[this]` or `protected[this]`), although they can be covariant. Consider this example, assuming your first example worked:

```
class Contravariant[-T](val other: T)

val stringList = List[Contravariant[String]](new Contravariant[Any](1))
val string: String = stringList.head.other //This can't work, because 1 is not a String
```

[Here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/jPDtiljATteofxFC7YIbTg) you can see what happens (I used `@uncheckedVariance` to make it work).

In the second example, `x` is simply a parameter to your constructor, and parameters can be contravariant, so it works.

Comment: *"fields cannot be contravariant"* Fields that are not `private[this]` or `protected[this]`.

Comment: @DmytroMitin I didn't think about those, since I've never used contravariant fields anyways. I've edited it into the answer now, hope it's correct this time.

Comment: Well, it's more about access than ability to be overridden.

Comment: I removed the override part.